# Create Hash that matches keys and increments value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a huge array that lists the day of the week in which the object was created, so I end up with an array similar to the following:

`["wednesday", "thursday", "friday"]` except that it contains 250,000 elements.

What I want to make is a new hash that will match the key and increment the value, so the result is as follows:

`{"wednesday": 250, "thursday": 600, "saturday": 120}`

How can I get achieve this outcome?

Here is my current code:

```
days = []

Invitation.all.each do |invitation|
  day = invitation.created_at.strftime("%A")
  days.push(day)
end

days
```

Comment: _"What I want to make is a new hash that will match the key and increment the value"_ – so you want to count the distinct elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Invitation.all.reduce(Hash.new(0)) do |memo, invitation|
  memo[invitation.created_at.strftime("%A")] += 1
  memo
end
```

`Hash.new(0)` makes a hash where the default values are 0. This is a general-purpose way to get counts from an array

Answer (score 4):

```
array = ["wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "wednesday", "wednesday", "friday"]

days = array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |e, total| 
  total[e] += 1 
end
```

will give you this :

```
{"wednesday"=>3, "thursday"=>1, "friday"=>2}
```

A 'one-line' solution of your problem:

```
days = Invitation.pluck(:created_at).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |e, total| 
  total[e.strftime("%A")] += 1 
end
```

Comment: Perhaps `each_with_object` would be more appropriate than `inject` here, the "artificial" `; total` return value for the block always looks odd to me.

Comment: In your last example, you can move the mapping into the `each_with_object` block: `total[e.created_at.strftime('%A')] += 1`

Comment: While I approved of this solution `pluck` would probably be more performant e.g. `Invitation.pluck(:created_at).each_with_object{...}` This way you don't have to pull in and map all the other attributes to an AR object just to access one of them

Comment: @engineersmnky you're right. I updated my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using postgresql, you can do the query at database level and just use Ruby to map the results:

```
Invitation
  .select("EXTRACT(DOW FROM created_at) AS day_of_the_week, COUNT(*) AS total_records")
  .group("day_of_the_week")
  .map {|result| [Date::DAYNAMES[result.day_of_the_week], result.total_records] }
  .to_h
#=> {"Friday"=>4, "Tuesday"=>2, "Thursday"=>5, "Monday"=>3, "Wednesday"=>5, "Saturday"=>3}
```

By this way you avoid to load all the Invitation objects and just perform one query.

Comment: Rails stores times in UTC (converting to and from as needed), so you have to adjust the timezone in your calculation to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If its a plain ruby `Array` and want to group by values

```
invites = ["wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "wednesday", "wednesday", "friday"]

invite_group = Hash.new(0)
invites.each { |invite| invite_group[invite] += 1 }

# invite_group => {"wednesday"=>3, "thursday"=>1, "friday"=>2}
```

Or by using `key?` method

```
invite_group = Hash.new
# invite_group = {}

invites.each { |invite| if invite_group.key?(invite); invite_group[invite] += 1; else invite_group[invite] = 1; end}
# # invite_group => {"wednesday"=>3, "thursday"=>1, "friday"=>2}
```